# Where should I add ServicePlacementPreferPrimaryDomainPolicyDescription in code or manifest file?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a cluster span regions and I want specify preferred domain. Problem is looking at sample code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-placement-policies, I have no idea where serviceDescription comes from. Anyone knows where I should have these code in my service fabric service code base?

Also, isn't there a similar way to specify it in service fabric manifest file instead of code change (Like how people specify frontend/backend placement)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to change a service description:

```
FabricClient fabricClient = new FabricClient();
StatefulServiceDescription serviceDescription = new StatefulServiceDescription();
serviceDescription.PlacementConstraints = "(HasSSD == true && SomeProperty >= 4)";
await fabricClient.ServiceManager.CreateServiceAsync(serviceDescription);
```

(source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#placement-constraint-and-node-property-syntax))

According to the XSD, you can define them as xml, similar to placement constraints.

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\schemas\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd*

Comment: Cool, the xsd is what I am looking for!

If I am using the code, should I write as a console app and run it after service deployment?

Comment: You can use either a small console app, or PowerShell, and run it as a `SetupEntryPoint`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security

Answer (score 0):

As per [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#placement-constraint-and-node-property-syntax), you can certainly configure it per code, like this:

```
FabricClient fabricClient = new FabricClient();
StatefulServiceDescription serviceDescription = new StatefulServiceDescription();
serviceDescription.PlacementConstraints = "(HasSSD == true && SomeProperty >= 4)";
// add other required servicedescription fields
//...
await fabricClient.ServiceManager.CreateServiceAsync(serviceDescription);
```

As for your question about where to do this from - depending on your needs, there are a few options:

- Write a separate application that gets run as part of CI/CD deployment pipeline (or do it via powershell `New-ServiceFabricService`)
  The problem with this approach is that it's a bit annoying for developers having to run this after each deployment - as such I prefer:
- Write a stateless service that gets instantiated by default (i.e. put an entry inside `<DefaultServices>` within `ApplicationManifest.xml`). Within this service you can then instantiate/modify placement constraints using `FabricClient`, policies, metrics - and drive these via application parameters/configuration
- Instantiate services lazily via your API gateway. This works particularly well for partitioned/stateful services (e.g. if you partition by tenantid) or where you want to maintain a pool of workers (e.g. `partition_id = random_number % pool size`), etc.

You can also configure placement constraints [declaratively](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/placement-constraints-with-service-fabric/) via application parameters. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work atm for placement policies (and probably not for [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-metrics) either).

If your needs are simple, then the declarative approach is probably simplest! As per above link, add a `[Stateless1_InstanceCount]` parameter in your application manifest file and put this under default services:

```
<DefaultServices>
  <Service Name="Stateless1">
    <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="Stateless1Type" InstanceCount="[Stateless1_InstanceCount]">
      <SingletonPartition />
      <PlacementConstraints>[Stateless1_PlacementConstraints]</PlacementConstraints>
    </StatelessService>
  </Service>
</DefaultServices>
```